# How can I use a while loop to continuously ask for input and stop the program if the user types in "quit"?

Tags: java, expression, calculator

I am currently taking an AP Computer Science class in my school and I ran into a little trouble with one of my projects! The project requires me to create a calculator that can evaluate an expression and then solve it. I have got most of that down, but I ran into a little trouble because my teacher asked me to use a while loop to continuously ask for input and display the answer, and I am stuck on that. To end the program the user has to type in "quit", does anyone have any tips?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Calculator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Welcome to the AP Computer Science calculator!!");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Please use the following format in your expressions: (double)(space)(+,-,*,/...)(space)(double)");
      System.out.println("or: (symbol)(space)(double)");
      System.out.println();
      next();
   }

   public static void next() {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter an expression, or quit to exit: ");
      String expression = kb.nextLine();
      next3(expression);  
   }
   public static void next3(String expression) {
         while (QuitFunction(expression)) {
            next2(expression);
            next();
         }   
   }

   public static void next2(String expression) {
      if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("+")) {
         System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " = " + (FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));          
      }
      else if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("*")) {
         System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " "  + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " = " + (FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) * SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));
      }
      else if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("-")) {
         System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " = " + (FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) - SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));       
      }
      else if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("/")) {
         System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " "  + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " = " + (FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) / SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));
      }
      else if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("^")) {
         System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " = " + Math.pow(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression),SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));
      }
      else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("|")) {
         System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression) + " = " + Math.abs(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
      }
      else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("v")) {
         System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression) + " = " + Math.sqrt(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
      }
      else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("~")) {
         double x = 0.0;
         System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression) + " = " + (Math.round(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression))+ x));
      }
      else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("s")) {
         System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression) + " = " + Math.sin(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
      }
      else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("c")) {
         System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression) + " = " + Math.cos(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
      }
      else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("t")) {
         System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression) + " = " + Math.tan(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression))); 
      } 
   }

      public static double FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(String expression) {
         String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
         String OperandOrOperator = tokens[0];
         double y = Double.parseDouble(OperandOrOperator);
         return y;         
   }
      public static double SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(String expression) {
         String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
         String OperandOrOperator = tokens[2];
         double y = Double.parseDouble(OperandOrOperator);
         return y;
   }
       public static String OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(String expression) {
         String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
         String OperandOrOperator = tokens[1];
         return OperandOrOperator;
   }
      public static String OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(String expression) {
         String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
         String OperandOrOperator = tokens[0];
         return OperandOrOperator; 
   }
      public static double OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(String expression) {
         String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
         String OperandOrOperator = tokens[1];
         double y = Double.parseDouble(OperandOrOperator);
         return y;  
   }
      public static boolean QuitFunction(String expression) {
         if (expression.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            return false;
         }
         else {
            return true;
         }
      }           
}
```

Comment: I would do exactly what you describe: Use a while loop to continuously ask for input; stop the program if the user enters "quit". If `if ("quit".equals(expression))` does not work out for you, then please describe the problem you are encountering.

Comment: Name your methods with something meaningful, `next` `next1`, `next2` `next3` doesn't say anything about what method actually does. Also since you are using loops, don't use recursion (you are calling `next3` inside `next` and in `next` inside `next3`). Other problem is that each time you call `next` you are creating separate instances of `Scanner` which doesn't seem right. Use one instance of Scanner which would read data from `System.in`.

Answer (score 1):

remove the chaining logic from your methods...

eg. (in pseudo code, since you're responsible for doing this for homework)

```
method A { ....  B(); }

method B { ..... C(); }

method C { .... D(); }

method D ....
```

instead do this:

```
while( boolean_condition )
{
    call method A();
    call method B();
    call method C();
    call method D();

    set boolean_condition to false if we are "done";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `next` function, instead of calling `next3` (btw, very expressive names), you can have something like:

```
while (!expression.equals("quit"))
    next3();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while which is always true to read the input repeatedly. For that use

```
while(true) {
   .......
}
```

After each time you read the input you can check whether the input is `quit` and if it is quit you can exit the program. For that use

```
if(expression.equals("quit")) { // to check whether the input is quit.
    System.exit(0); // for exiting the program
}
```

#### CODE:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the AP Computer Science calculator!!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out
                .println("Please use the following format in your expressions: (double)(space)(+,-,*,/...)(space)(double)");
        System.out.println("or: (symbol)(space)(double)");
        System.out.println();
        while (true) {
            next();
        }
    }

    public static void next() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an expression, or quit to exit: ");
        String expression = kb.nextLine();
        if (expression.equals("quit")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            next3(expression);
        }
    }
```

In your code names of the methods are really confusing.

> - A method name should describe the purpose of the method, making your
>     code self-documenting and reducing the need for additional comments.
> - Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter
>     lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. [(**naming conventions**)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
> - By
>     Following the naming conventions it can make your code easily readable
>     by another person.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you described the problems you saw with the OPs code and why you chose to do this the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

With slight changes, to the current code.

changes done in `next()` and `next3()` methods.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the AP Computer Science calculator!!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out
                .println("Please use the following format in your expressions: (double)(space)(+,-,*,/...)(space)(double)");
        System.out.println("or: (symbol)(space)(double)");
        System.out.println();
        next();
    }

    public static void next() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an expression, or quit to exit: ");
        while (kb.hasNext()) {
            String expression = kb.nextLine();
            next3(expression);
            System.out.print("Enter an expression, or quit to exit: ");
        }
    }

    public static void next3(String expression) {
        if (QuitFunction(expression)) {
            next2(expression);
            next();
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void next2(String expression) {
        if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("+")) {
            System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " "
                    + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)
                    + " = "
                    + (FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("*")) {
            System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " "
                    + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)
                    + " = "
                    + (FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) * SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("-")) {
            System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " "
                    + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)
                    + " = "
                    + (FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) - SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("/")) {
            System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " "
                    + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)
                    + " = "
                    + (FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression) / SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression).equals("^")) {
            System.out.println(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)
                    + " "
                    + OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(expression)
                    + " "
                    + SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)
                    + " = "
                    + Math.pow(FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression),
                            SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("|")) {
            System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)
                    + " = " + Math.abs(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("v")) {
            System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)
                    + " = " + Math.sqrt(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("~")) {
            double x = 0.0;
            System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)
                    + " = " + (Math.round(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)) + x));
        } else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("s")) {
            System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)
                    + " = " + Math.sin(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("c")) {
            System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)
                    + " = " + Math.cos(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
        } else if (OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression).equals("t")) {
            System.out.println(OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(expression) + " " + OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)
                    + " = " + Math.tan(OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(expression)));
        }
    }

    public static double FirstOperandFor2OperandExpressions(String expression) {
        String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
        String OperandOrOperator = tokens[0];
        double y = Double.parseDouble(OperandOrOperator);
        return y;
    }

    public static double SecondOperandFor2OperandExpressions(String expression) {
        String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
        String OperandOrOperator = tokens[2];
        double y = Double.parseDouble(OperandOrOperator);
        return y;
    }

    public static String OperatorFor2OperandExpressions(String expression) {
        String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
        String OperandOrOperator = tokens[1];
        return OperandOrOperator;
    }

    public static String OperatorFor1OperandExpressions(String expression) {
        String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
        String OperandOrOperator = tokens[0];
        return OperandOrOperator;
    }

    public static double OperandFor1OperatorExpressions(String expression) {
        String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");
        String OperandOrOperator = tokens[1];
        double y = Double.parseDouble(OperandOrOperator);
        return y;
    }

    public static boolean QuitFunction(String expression) {
        if (expression.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
Welcome to the AP Computer Science calculator!!

Please use the following format in your expressions: (double)(space)(+,-,*,/...)(space)(double)
or: (symbol)(space)(double)

Enter an expression, or quit to exit: 3 - 2
3.0 - 2.0 = 1.0
Enter an expression, or quit to exit: quit
Goodbye!
```